# Starting point of execution in sqlite

Tags: c, sqlite

I was trying to understand sqlite source code.

I was lookin to find that, when on CLI we do **$sqlite abcd.db**, where does the control transfers to , which function are called?

---

I've to make some changes whenever I create a new database or open it i.e. $sqlite abcd.db

Comment: `main()`. But probably you are looking at the wrong place, and you are reading the source of the SQLite3 **library** (which itself has no `main()`, for obvious reasons).

Comment: thank you ..so when I do `$sqlite abcd.db, where does the control transfers to` ?

Comment: @user182904: `main` in the `sqlite` command.

Comment: Sir thank you for answers ...but pls can you please give a little explanatory for beginner....
How to see this all functionality in source code, so that I can understand it.
How to look into source code of sqlite command. 
The source code given here [link]http://www.sqlite.org/2014/sqlite-amalgamation-3080403.zip is of sqlite library. So where to look for sqlite command ..??

Comment: @user3477950 actually, I've to make some changes whenever I create a new database or open it i.e. $sqlite abcd.db.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The amalgamation build of SQLite includes two C files. `sqlite3.c` is the SQLite *library* source code, and does not contain an entry point, since it is not a program.

The SQLite shell is implemented in the file `shell.c`, which is a standard C program source file with a `main` function (which is on line 3570 in my version).